# Python: break loop at any point

Tags: python, loops, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have a python script on a Raspberry Pi 2 and I would like o break a loop if at any point `buttonpressed=True`

So something like:

```
while True:
    try:
        do_something_pythonic()
    except buttonpressed=True:
        break
```

Comment: i dont really see a question here ... but i tried to answer... maybe i nailed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    while not self.button_pressed:
         do_pythonic()

...
def OnButtonPress(self,evt):
    self.button_pressed = True
```